# how to use grep to search for a word which can be followed and/or preceded by a non alphabetical character?

Tags: command-line, grep

I want to search for javascript variables. 
So If my variable is geometry I want grep to return all lines like this
e.g.

```
geometry.property1
myfunc(geometry)
```

etc..

but not these

```
geometryMark.property2
```

or

```
mygeometry.property3
```

So basically dont return instances where geometry is followed and/or preceded by a-z or A-Z characters

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do that with the `-w` switch

```
-w, --word-regexp
          at  the  beginning  of  the  line,  or  preceded  by  a non-word
          of  the  line  or  followed by a non-word constituent character.
```

e.g. the matches for your examples are

```
$ grep -w 'geometry' myfile
geometry.property1
myfunc(geometry)
```

and the non-matches

```
$ grep -vw 'geometry' myfile
geometryMark.property2
mygeometry.property3
```